# Civicase . how to copy a timeline or sequence

Tags: civicase

we're setting up a few case types, each of which has half a dozen timelines. Once we have set up one timeline, is there any way of duplicating it? I imagine that the timeline definition is stored in XML somewhere, in which case can I simply cut and paste in the XML?

Thanks.

Using CiviCRM 4.6.8 and Joomla 3.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML which contains the timeline data is stored in civicrm_case_type.definition as a BLOB.

Comment: Thanks! I'll investigate how easy it is to extract the XML and then update the BLOB with amended XML.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in principle yes. But my experience with CiviCase is mainly CiviCRM 4.4 and before. I do not know where the case type XML files are stored from 4.5 onwards but you should be able to find that in the CiviCRM documentation wiki.

Comment: From Angela's reply, it seems that the XML isn't directly accessible any more. Makes sense, with the new UI.